# How do I represent hierarchical data in Cloud Firestore using a struct?

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I was taking a look at [how hierarchical data works in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data), and was wondering how that would best translate into a Go struct.

In the linked example, there is a collection of chat rooms, and each chat room document has two fields: a name and a collection of messages.

Would the following be a good way of representing a chat room using a go struct, given that there will be fairly frequent writes to and reads from the messages collection? I would also want to access the messages in the collection in the Go code.

```
type ChatRoom struct {
    Name     string
    Messages *firestore.CollectionRef
}
```

This definition seems to compile and works fine, but I was wondering if there are better or more idiomatic ways of going about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents don't mention a CollectionRef being supported in a document. So I am not sure if that will work. You can see what I am referring to [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/firestore/docref.go#L97).

On the other hand I don't think you really gain anything from it since you can access the collection by doing the following.

```
client.Collection("chatroom/" + <NAME> + "/messages")
```

Also I don't think it is good practice to entangle a high level type like ChatRoom to a firestore implementation. So I would remove it and create an interface that hides the details of how ChatRooms and Messages are stored. You can do something like this.

```
type Repo interface {
    GetChatRoom(name string) (ChatRoom, error)
    GetMessages(name string) ([]Messages, error)
}
```